# Laravel: Error using whereRaw query with IN clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

(First time asking question)
I tried running the following query in laravel

```
$cats = ['x1', 'x2'];
$pars = ['Par1' => 'd1', 'Par2' => $cats];
$result = Projecto::whereRaw('(  (ESTADO = :Par1 )  and   (CATEGORIA in (:Par2 ) ) )', $pars)->get();
```

but I get the following error.

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (SQL: select * from `tbl_projecto` where (  (ESTADO = :Par1 )  and   (CATEGORIA in (:Par2 ) ) ))

{"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: HY093): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (SQL: select * from `tbl_projecto` where (  (ESTADO = :Par1 )  and   (CATEGORIA in (:Par2 ) ) ))
```

I tried removing `Par2` and the second condition but the error persists

Comment: Curiosity, is there a reason you need to do `->whereRaw()` here? You could do `->where(function ($query) use ($cats) { return $query->where('ESTADO', 'd1')->whereIn('CATEGORIA', $cats); })`, or similar. Laravel supports nested where clauses, so that query _should_ generate `WHERE (ESTADO = 'd1' AND CATEGORIA IN (1, 2))`

Comment: Yes, this is a result of an internal query generator. It builds the quero dynamically. I Just put the resulting query here that returns the same erros.

Comment: Understandable. I don't personally recognize the SQL syntax being used there, and I've never personally tried to parameterize an `IN (...)` clause (since Laravel has `->whereIn()`) Hopefully someone with more experience can help, but you should also tag your question with the appropriate DB system, like `mysql`, `postgresql`, etc.

Comment: "this is a result of an internal query generator" maybe you should fix that instead?

Comment: The purpose of the question is to find a way to  modify the generator so that it can output the correct query. I'm new to laravel, i'm porting a asp.net project to laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *whereRaw()* with *IN* clause works like PDO that doesn't accept arrays as multi value parameter.
The only way to make it work is to provide a parameter for each element of the array:

```php
$pars =['p1' => 'x1', 'p2' => 'x2'];
$result=Projecto::whereRaw('CATEGORIA in (:p1, :p2))', $pars)->get();
```

which makes it less convenient.

A workaround can be using a loop to fill the placeholders:

```php
$valueList = ['x1', 'x2'];

$pars = [];
$placeholders = '';

foreach ($valueList as $k => $v) {
    
    $pars["p$k"] = $v;
    $placeholders .= ($k ? ', ' : '') . ":p$k";
}

$result = Projecto::whereRaw("CATEGORIA in ($placeholders)", $pars)->get();
```

A better approach may be to use question marks as placeholders:

```php
$pars = ['x1', 'x2'];
$qry = 'CATEGORIA in (' . 
       rtrim (str_repeat('?,', count($pars)), ',') . 
       ')';

$result = Projecto::whereRaw($qry, $pars)->get();
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. I went with your first option